# ASP.NET TreeView CheckBoxes form labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, accessibility

I am using a ASP.NET 3.5 TreeView with Checkboxes enabled and being populated programmatically on the server. I am trying to make it 508 compliant, so I need to tag the label with the id of the checkbox. Eg. http://www.10sharpdesign.com/accessibility/forms/3b-ii-labels-checkboxes.html

The default output HTML is not tagging the checkboxes with the labels, how do I make it do that?

The output is:

```
<input type="checkbox"
    name="ctl00_mainContent_tvSelectedFiltersn4CheckBox"
    id="ctl00_mainContent_tvSelectedFiltersn4CheckBox"
    checked="checked" />
<span class="ctl00_mainContent_tvSelectedFilters_0 ctl00_mainContent_tvSelectedFilters_1"
    id="ctl00_mainContent_tvSelectedFilterst4">Pacific Islanders</span>
```

Comment: Not sure about the TreeView, but with most other form elements, providing the [AssociatedControlID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) will make .NET spit out a proper label with explicit association to the control.

Comment: nope, TreeView will not do that for some reason, there is no AssociatedControlID

Comment: You can use JavaScript. Run the following JQuery code on document ready.

$("#tree").each(function(){var n = $(this).next(); if(n.attr("href") == null) n.html("<label for=" + this.id +">" + n.html() + "</label>");})

Answer (score 0):

There is something called Control adapters on asp.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx

You can overwrite completely the way a control is being rendered. It is used in conjuction with the app_browers and the .browser files.

There is something called css friendly control adapters on codeplex:
http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/

that might serve as an example to get you started.